# How to use xcodebuild in Xcode 7 with a watch extension

Tags: xcodebuild, xcode7, ios9, watchos-2, xcode7-beta3

Our command used to be like this

```
xcodebuild -configuration Release -target "xxx" -sdk iphoneos9.0 -scheme "xxx" archive
```

Now in Xcode 7, we get this error:

```
Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphoneos9.0

=== BUILD TARGET xxx WatchKit Extension OF PROJECT Mobile WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform
```

How do we specify to use iOS 9.0 SDK and the watchos 2.0 SDK?

Answer (score 25):

If you need a simulator build run this:

```
xcodebuild -workspace WorkspaceName.xcworkspace -scheme SchemeWithWatchOS2Target -destination 'name=iPhone 6' build
```

And if you need a device build run this:

```
xcodebuild -workspace WorkspaceName.xcworkspace -scheme SchemeWithWatchOS2Target build
```

The trick is that for any build you need to remove `-sdk` option. For simulator build you need to specify `-destination` which should be `iPhone 6` or `iPhone 6 Plus`. And for devices builds you skip `-destination`.

Comment: Removing the -sdk argument does the trick for me as well. Great hint. +1

Comment: that way I'm still having problem if I want to run tests, specifically I receive:

There was a problem starting the test bundle: Testing with the 'iphoneos' SDK is not yet supported.  Instead, test with the simulator SDK by setting '-sdk iphonesimulator'.

Comment: @dev_mush, you need to provide `-destination` in order to run tests.

Comment: @dev_mush As the time of writing (Xcode 7), running unit tests on a physical device isn't supported. This means that you cannot use `iphoneos` for `sdk`. That's what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons that you're seeing this error, but it boils down to dependencies. If you select a scheme that builds an iOS target, then you don't have a problem using the following command. Note that I used `iphoneos` to automatically select the latest SDK.

```
xcodebuild -configuration Release -target "ios" -sdk iphoneos -scheme "ios" build
```

The problem you're running into is triggered because of a dependency on the watchOS extension. I've created a sample project and added a watchOS application. In the build phases tab, you see in the **Dependencies** section that the **iOS** target has a dependency on the **WatchOS** target.

[image]

This isn't a problem if you specify a `destination` in your build command. But it does give a problem if you tell `xcodebuild` to build with a specific SDK. Why? Because the WatchOS target cannot be built with the iOS SDK. If you specify `iphoneos` as the SDK, the build will fail.

Specifying a destination solves the problem, but know that you are using a specific simulator. If you use the same command on a different machine and that simulator isn't available, then the build will fail.

To be honest, I don't know if there's a middle road that lets you select the latest SDK and still use the correct SDK for each target, regardless of dependencies. If you remove the dependency of the **iOS** target, then the above build command shouldn't fail. You may also need to update the scheme you're using.

Comment: `-destination 'generic/platform=iphonesimulator'` or `-destination 'generic/platform=iOS'` allows to use the command on any machine.