Running xcodebuild on iOS+WatchKit+WidgetKit App causes `The stickers icon set or app icon set named “AppIcon” did not have any applicable content`
We are currently building an iOS app with CI/CD from Github Action.
Our project incorporates Watch and widget extensions into an iOS app!
It is possible to build and archive from XCode.
However, when I run the following command in Github Action to build, I get an error.
Command with error
xcodebuild -project “Project.xcodeproj” -scheme “${{ matrix.scheme }}” -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator, name=iPhone 14,OS name=iPhone 14,OS=latest' clean build -verbose

Error Message
The following build command failed: ` CompileAssetCatalogV
    CompileAssetCatalogVariant thinned out /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-bbxdduymmzeemvgztykqihaxymvx/Build/.Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectWatch.app /Users/runner/work/Project/ProjectWatch/Preview Contents/Preview Assets.xcassets / Users/runner/work/CowManagement/Project/ProjectWatch/Assets.xcassets (in target 'ProjectWatch' from project 'Project ').

workflow.yml

  build:

    runs-on: macos-latest

    strategy:

      matrix:

        scheme: [Project]

    steps:

      - name: Checkout source code

        uses: actions/checkout@v3



      - name: Set up Xcode

        uses: maxim-lobanov/setup-xcode@v1

        with:

          xcode-version: latest-stable



      - name: Set up Swift

        uses: swift-actions/setup-swift@v2

        with:

          swift-version: "5.10"



      - name: Cache Swift dependencies

        uses: actions/cache@v3

        with:

          path: ~/.swiftpm

          key: swiftpm-${{ matrix.scheme }}

          restore-keys: |

            swiftpm-



      - name: Build for ${{ matrix.scheme }}

        run: |

          xcodebuild -project "Project.xcodeproj" -scheme "${{ matrix.scheme }}" -sdk　iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14,OS=latest' clean build -verbose



What we are looking for
Run xcodebuild from the GitHub action.
Confirm that the build runs without problems.
Checked
Other things checked
Check that there is an Assets folder in the project.
AppIcon should be set.
Make sure that the archive from XCode and the upload from TestFlight are working properly.
After uploading, Apple's review must be completed without any problems.

Resolved.
The problem seemed to be that I was specifying option -sdk
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31953937/27996616
